# MSSQL - mssql_select_db work in 95%, but sometimes its unable to select DB

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and PHP 5.2.

To establish a connection and to select the DB I use this code:

```
  $connection = mssql_pconnect(SYSTEM_DB_HOST, SYSTEM_DB_USER, SYSTEM_DB_PASSW);
  mssql_select_db (SYSTEM_DB_NAME ,$connection);

 $connection2 = mssql_pconnect(SYSTEM_DB_HOST, SYSTEM_DB_USER, SYSTEM_DB_PASSW);
  mssql_select_db (SYSTEM_DB_NAME ,$connection2);
```

There is no error and everything works fine most of the time, but sometimes I get this error:

```
Warning: mssql_select_db(): Unable to select database: dbMyDB in ... on line 44 
Warning: mssql_select_db(): Unable to select database: dbMyDB in ... on line 47
```

I dont know why. I dont know where the issue could be. I dont know how to debug it.

Anyone some tips?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try remove `p` from `mssql_pconnect`. Your driver don't persist. 
Configure your `mssql.ini` or change your drive.

Replace to this: `mssql_connect`